# How to run Medisoft Patient Accounting Demo on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I installed Medisoft Patient Accounting Demo but every time I try to run it, I get this error:

`tblExclusiveNew: One of the Database property or the AdsConnection property must have a value.`
I click OK and then get this error:

`Exception AdsConnectionError in module MW.EXE at 001FA701.  Must specify connection string before getting a server connection.`

The program then immediately exits.

Then a get this error:

```
Ar3import -An error has occurred 
dmIPCCommunication: No core product found
```

I click close and then:

```
Ar3import-An error has occurred 
An unspecified error has occurred, please call tech support
```

Googling was no help.  Even the Medisoft tech on the Medisoft forum thread I found was unable to fix it.  Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the similar error...using Windows 7
I called the MediSoft Tech Support at McGraw-Hill
Hold down <kbd>F7</kbd>
Double-click the Medisoft program icon.
OK

Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to Super User! Unfortunately, I no longer have access to either the software or the hardware so I can't test this.

Comment: This actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just got off the phone with the company. I was in the middle of reinstalling the program when I got a hold of them. Of course of all times during the installation it gave me an error message that setup.cab could not be read. Had to completely uninstall, manually delete files, and reinstall again.

While the computer I installed this on was a Vista machine, it still had the same `tblExclusiveNew: One of the Database property or the AdsConnection property must have a value`. error message. If it is the same problem for Windows 7, this hugely 'complicated' solution should be the fix you need:

1. Hold down F7
2. Double-click the Medisoft program icon.

Enjoy!

Comment: This actually works!

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the F7 key, and enter the location directory of cimo7e (C:\MediData) then click on OK

Answer (score 0):

Contact the vendor. This is not a problem we can fix here.

As a software developer myself, it looks like either it wasn't installed correctly, or the configuration is broken, because it can't connect to its database

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the software, then re-install it using compatibility mode, right click on the installer and select Properties, tick the "run this program in compatibility mode for:", select the OS it was designed for, then also tick the Run as Administrator box, close properties and execute to install, see if it works now.

You may have to do the compatibility trick for the program executable once it is installed.